Distinguishing between $\mathbb{C}P^2 \times S^2$ and $S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^4 \vee S^4 \vee S^6$
I am trying to show prove/disprove that the spaces $X=\mathbb{C}P^2 \times S^2$ and $Y=S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^4 \vee S^4 \vee S^6$ are not homotopy equivalent. I have checked that they have the same (co)homology groups. I am trying to use the cup product structures on the cohomology rings to show that the spaces are not homotopy equivalent.
I am convinced that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two generators of the $H^2$ group of $Y$ (which is $\mathbb{Z^2}$), then $\alpha \smile \beta = 0$, since this can be viewed as an element in $H^4(S^2 \vee S^2)= 0.$ I think it is possible to show that the cup product of two generators of $H^2(X)$, however, is nonzero. My question is if this true, how do I show this? Any alternate argument to show that $X$ and $Y$ are (not) homotopic would also be appreciated.
Note: I also observed that $H^4(X) = H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2) \otimes H^2(S^2) \oplus H^4(\mathbb{C}P^2) \otimes H^0(S^2)$, but not sure if this is useful here. All (co)homologies are considered in the $\mathbb{Z}$ ring.

Big hint: The Kuenneth isomorphism $H^(X) \cong H^(\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^2) \otimes H^*(S^2)$ is an isomorphism of graded rings.

There are related questions (with answers), like https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2066306/42781 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1517304/42781. Do either of those answer your question?

@JohnPalmieri I have come across a couple of them, but having trouble understanding how the Kunneth theorem is applied.

@MutasimMim Perhaps it would be better to ask about that, then. This question can be resolved in essentially the same way as either of the two John linked, via Kuenneth.

@BenSteffan I think this particular problem still has value since in the other questions I have come across, the Kunneth theorem translates the $H^.$ groups into a single term, while for the $X$ space in my question, there are more than one.

@MutasimMim I have no idea what you mean by "translates the $H$ groups into a single term." The only marked difference I see is that in your question one factor already comes with a non-trivial ring structure in cohomology.

As I hinted in the comments, the Künneth theorem yields an isomorphism $H^*(X) \cong H^*(\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^2) \otimes H^*(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^3) \otimes H^*(S^2)$ of graded rings. In particular, the element $x \otimes 1 \in H^2(X)$ (here $1 \in H^0(S^2)$ is the unit) squares to $0 \neq x^2 \otimes 1 \in H^4(X)$ whereas the ring structure on $H^*(Y)$ is completely trivial, so the two spaces cannot be homotopy equivalent.
We need not rely on the ring structure on $ H^*(\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^2)$ either: Assuming that $X = (S^2 \vee S^4) \times S^2$ instead, let $\alpha \in H^2(S^2 \vee S^4)$ and $\beta \in H^2(S^2)$ be generators. Then
$$
    (\alpha \otimes 1) \cdot (1 \otimes \beta) = \alpha \otimes \beta \neq 0
$$
as elements of $H^*(S^2 \vee S^4) \otimes H^*(S^2) \cong H^*(X)$  (here 1 again denotes the respective identities in degree 0) for the same result.

How do we know that $x^2 \otimes 1 \not = 0$?

@MutasimMim It's a generator of the free group $H^4(\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^2) \otimes H^0(S^2) \subset H^(X) \otimes H^(S^2)$. Put differently, you know that $x^2 \neq 0$ and $1 \neq 0$ in $H^0(S^2)$, so $x^2 \otimes 1 \neq 0$ since everything is free.
